# How can I write given SQL query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I write below SQL query in Laravel

```sql
SELECT
    notifications.*,
    if(notifications.branchID=0, 'All', (
        select
            group_concat(name)
        from
            branches
        where
            find_in_set(id,notifications.branchID)
    )) as brcName
FROM
    notifications
WHERE
    id = 2
```

Comment: First write it correctly in SQL RAW query so we can "translate" it to elloquent Buery Builder or something like that... and format your code.

Comment: @hicham-o-sfh this thing will return perfect result on mysql

Comment: so mention your MySQL version, and post all your code formatted correctly please.

Comment: got solution dude, cheers! ✔

solution is 

DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT notifications.*, if(notifications.branchID=0,'All',(select group_concat(name) FROM branches where find_in_set(id,notifications.branchID))) as brcName FROM notifications WHERE id = :id"), array(
                                               'id' => $id,
                                             ));

Answer (score 2):

Query:

```sql
SELECT
    notifications.*,
    if(notifications.branchID=0, 'All', (
        select
            group_concat(name)
        from
            branches
        where
            find_in_set(id,notifications.branchID)
    )) as brcName
FROM
    notifications
WHERE
    id = 2
```

---

Query builder:

```
DB::table('notifications')
->select('notifications.*')
->addSelect(DB::raw("if(notifications.branchID=0, 'All', (
        select
            group_concat(name)
        from
            branches
        where
            find_in_set(id,notifications.branchID)
    )) as brcName"))
->where('id', 2);
```

---

Eloquent model:

```php
class Notification extends Model
{
    public function getBrcNameAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->branchID === 0) {
            return 'All';
        }

        return $this->branches()->select('group_concat(name) AS brcName')->first()->brcName;
    }

    public function branches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Branch::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: throwing error 

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$brcName

Comment: What happens if you `dd($this->branches()->select('group_concat(name) AS brcName')->first())`?

Comment: found solution bruh, thank alot for answer!

Comment: this one also worked man !  let's make 2 green tick on that post. :D

Answer (score 0):

```php
$id = some_id;

$query = DB::select(
    DB::raw("SELECT notifications.*, if(notifications.branchID=0,'All',(select group_concat(name) FROM branches where find_in_set(id,notifications.branchID))) as brcName FROM notifications WHERE id = :id"),
    array('id' => $id)
);
```

Comment: It works, but it can hardly be called "Laravel solution" :D

Comment: CIAO, let it be buddy  it's urgent buddy so i have to